# how can i use setinterval on a inputfield?

Tags: javascript, html

i have an issue with (html) javascript and i hope someone can help me out here/

i am making my own wine cooler in javascript,
you can open and close the door, if you open the door the original temperature of 7.1 will raise with 0.9 , and after you close it it will automatically decrease to 7.1 (0.2 per 5 minutes), i used setinterval to do this.

now i want to add an inputfield input id="desiredtemp" type="text"

and another =button button type="button" id="desired">Set desired temperature /button

i did this because i want to add a function that you can lower the temperature to any temperature you want instead of the original 7.1 when you close the door. but i cant  get it working

any help would be really appreciated.

heres my code so far

```
var degree = 7.2;//graden
            var counter = 0;//counter gebruikt om stand aan te geven van wijnkoeler 




            function myFunction() {
                if (counter === 0) {
                    document.getElementById("dicht").src = "images/open.jpg";
                    degree = degree + 0.9;
                    temp.innerHTML = degree; //+ " " + "graden celsius in de wijnkoeler";
                    console.log("Wijnkoeler is geopend");
                    console.log("Temperatuur " + "is " + "nu " + degree + " Graden");
                    counter = 1;
                }

                else if (counter === 1) {
                    document.getElementById("dicht").src = "images/dicht.jpg";
                    console.log("de temperatuur van de Wijnkoeler is gestegen naar" + degree);
                    console.log("De motor wordt gestart");
                    console.log("...");
                    console.log("...");
                    console.log("...");
                    var id = window.setInterval(function() {
                        degree = parseFloat(Math.max(7.2, (degree - 0.2)).toPrecision(2));//telkens 0.2 graden eraf -- afronden
                        if (degree == 7.2) {                                              //als het weer 7.2 graden is motor uitschakelen     
                            window.clearInterval(id);
                            console.log("De temperatuur is weer op " + degree + "graden" );
                            console.log("De motor wordt uitgeschakeld")
                        }
                        temp.innerHTML = degree;
                    }, 5 *60 *1000);                                                       //elke 5 minuten
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
```

html:

```
<body>



        <button onclick="myFunction();">Open/Close</button>
        <p id="Temperatuur">Temperatuur</p>
        <p id="temp">7.2</p>

        <input id="desiredtemp" type="text">

        <button type="button" id="desired">Set desired temperature</button> 

        <img id ="dicht" src="images/dicht.jpg"/>



    </body>
```

thanks again

Comment: Why not just hide the button until you need it?

Comment: how do you mean?? i want there to be an option to decrease the temperature to another number when you open it.

Comment: Instead of adding the button, have it there from the start, hidden. The unhide it when needed.

Comment: yeah but my problem now is i dont know how to write the code that will decrease the temperature to whats written in the input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make a few changes.  First, get rid of the constant `7.2` in your `setTimeout` function and replace with a variable:

```
var targetTemp = document.getElementById("desiredtemp").value || 7.2; //get from textbox, or use 7.2 if no value set
```

Then, reference it instead of the constant:

```
degree = parseFloat(Math.max(targetTemp, (degree - 0.2)).toPrecision(2));
```

and:

```
if (degree == targetTemp) {
```

Finally, you can remove the "Set desired temperature" button as you don't really need it.

You can see all of these changes in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/magnafides/56w6E/3/

Comment: thanks for your commment it helped but i want the temerature to raise with 0.9 everytime i open the cooler(whitout a maximum). end when i open it in my browser it keeps saying "paused in debugger" what is that?? thanks for you help man

Comment: `debugger` is a special keyword that certain browsers recognize, and will cause the browser debugger to pause at that line.  You can then use debugging tools including typing in some commands in the console to test certain values/commands.  I didn't mean to leave it in.  Anyways, the answer and link are updated.

Comment: @user3058036 - If my answer works I'd appreciate it if you accepted it.  If not let me know why.